# Django Error: Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering

Tags: python, django, osqa

I'm trying to setup a Django site (OSQA) and can't get it working.

There are a few issues and one of them is when I tried to view a user's profile, I got the following exception:

Can someone please point out where the problem might be?

```
TemplateSyntaxError at /users/2/allenq/
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'ask_to_me' with arguments '(2, u'allenq')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://123.243.100.125/users/2/allenq/
Django Version: 1.3.4
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'ask_to_me' with arguments '(2, u'allenq')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render, line 450
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.6.6
Python Path:    
['/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/elementtree-1.2.7_20070827_preview-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Markdown-2.2.0-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/html5lib-0.95-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django_rosetta-0.6.8-py2.6.egg',
 '/usr/lib64/python26.zip',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/webkit-1.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg-info',
 '/usr/local/src',
 '/usr/local/src/osqa',
 '/usr/local/src/osqa/forum/markdownext']
Server time:    ???, 24 ?? 2012 22:58:23 +1100
Template error

In template /usr/local/src/osqa/forum/skins/default/templates/users/info.html, error at line 31
Caught NoReverseMatch while rendering: Reverse for 'ask_to_me' with arguments '(2, u'allenq')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
21                  </tr>
22                  <tr>
23                      <td align="center">
24                          {% if not view_user.is_suspended %}
25                              <div class="scoreNumber" id="user-reputation">{{view_user.reputation|intcomma}}</div>
26                              <p><b style="color:#777;">{% trans "reputation" %}</b></p>
27                          {% else %}
28                              <div class="scoreNumber">{% trans "Suspended" %}</div>
29                              <p>{{ view_user.suspension.extra.publicmsg }}</p>
30                          {% endif %}
31                              <div class="scoreNumber" id="user-reputation"><a href="{% url ask_to_me view_user.id view_user.username%}">{% trans "Ask to me" %}</a></div>
32                      </td>
33                  </tr>
34              </table>
35          </td>
36          <td width="360" style="vertical-align: top;">
37          {% if can_view_private %}{% user_menu request.user view_user %}{% endif %}
38              <table class="user-details">
39                  <tr>
40                      <th colspan="2" align="left"><h3>{% trans "Registered user" %}</h3></th>
41                  </tr>
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
            response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
? Local vars
/usr/local/src/osqa/forum/modules/decorators.py in decorated
        return decoratable(*args, **kwargs) ...
? Local vars
/usr/local/src/osqa/forum/modules/decorators.py in __call__
            res = dec(res, *args, **kwargs) ...
? Local vars
/usr/local/src/osqa/forum/views/users.py in result
        return render_to_response(template, context, context_instance=RequestContext(request)) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py in render_to_response
    return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs), **httpresponse_kwargs) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py in render_to_string
    return t.render(context_instance) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render
        return self._render(context) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render
        bits.append(self.render_node(node, context)) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py in render_node
        result = node.render(context) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render
        bits.append(self.render_node(node, context)) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py in render_node
        result = node.render(context) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render
        bits.append(self.render_node(node, context)) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py in render_node
        result = node.render(context) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py in render
        result = block.nodelist.render(context) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render
        bits.append(self.render_node(node, context)) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py in render_node
        result = node.render(context) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py in render
        result = block.nodelist.render(context) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render
        bits.append(self.render_node(node, context)) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py in render_node
        result = node.render(context) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py in render
    return self.render_template(self.template, context) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py in render_template
    output = template.render(context) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render
        return self._render(context) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/base.py in render
        bits.append(self.render_node(node, context)) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/debug.py in render_node
        result = node.render(context) ...
? Local vars
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in render
            raise e ...
? Local vars
Request information

GET
No GET data
POST
No POST data
FILES
No FILES data
COOKIES
Variable    Value
sessionid   
'1e7a11ca5a8631425ad03fd4973e57dc'
META
Variable    Value
mod_wsgi.listener_port  
'80'
HTTP_COOKIE 
'sessionid=1e7a11ca5a8631425ad03fd4973e57dc'
mod_wsgi.listener_host  
''
SERVER_SOFTWARE 
'Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)'
SCRIPT_NAME 
u''
mod_wsgi.handler_script 
''
SERVER_SIGNATURE    
'<address>Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at 123.243.100.125 Port 80</address>\n'
REQUEST_METHOD  
'GET'
PATH_INFO   
u'/users/2/allenq/'
SERVER_PROTOCOL 
'HTTP/1.1'
QUERY_STRING    
''
HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET 
'ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3'
HTTP_USER_AGENT 
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4'
HTTP_CONNECTION 
'keep-alive'
HTTP_REFERER    
'http://123.243.100.125/questions/unanswered/'
SERVER_NAME 
'123.243.100.125'
REMOTE_ADDR 
'123.243.100.125'
mod_wsgi.request_handler    
'wsgi-script'
wsgi.url_scheme 
'http'
PATH_TRANSLATED 
'/usr/local/src/osqa/osqa.wsgi/users/2/allenq/'
SERVER_PORT 
'80'
wsgi.multiprocess   
False
mod_wsgi.input_chunked  
'0'
SERVER_ADDR 
'192.168.0.10'
DOCUMENT_ROOT   
'/usr/local/src/osqa/forum'
mod_wsgi.process_group  
'osqa'
SCRIPT_FILENAME 
'/usr/local/src/osqa/osqa.wsgi'
SERVER_ADMIN    
'admin@your.server.com'
wsgi.input  
<mod_wsgi.Input object at 0x7f1d982f5670>
HTTP_HOST   
'123.243.100.125'
wsgi.multithread    
True
mod_wsgi.callable_object    
'application'
REQUEST_URI 
'/users/2/allenq/'
HTTP_ACCEPT 
'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
wsgi.version    
(1, 1)
GATEWAY_INTERFACE   
'CGI/1.1'
wsgi.run_once   
False
wsgi.errors 
<mod_wsgi.Log object at 0x7f1d982f5af0>
REMOTE_PORT 
'11611'
HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE    
'en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6'
mod_wsgi.version    
(3, 2)
mod_wsgi.application_group  
'localhost.localdomain|'
mod_wsgi.script_reloading   
'1'
wsgi.file_wrapper   
''
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING    
'gzip,deflate,sdch'
Settings
Using settings module osqa.settings
Setting Value
USE_L10N    
False
USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
False
APP_PROTOCOL    
'http'
LANGUAGE_CODE   
'zh_CN'
ROOT_URLCONF    
'urls'
MANAGERS    
()
APP_URL 
'http://127.0.0.1'
DEFAULT_CHARSET 
'utf-8'
APP_DOMAIN  
'127.0.0.1'
STATIC_ROOT 
''
TEST_DATABASE_CHARSET   
None
LOG_FILENAME    
'django.osqa.log'
MESSAGE_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.messages.storage.user_messages.LegacyFallbackStorage'
DATABASE_HOST   
'127.0.0.1'
IGNORABLE_404_STARTS    
('/cgi-bin/', '/_vti_bin', '/_vti_inf')
SEND_BROKEN_LINK_EMAILS 
False
URL_VALIDATOR_USER_AGENT    
'Django/1.3.4 (http://www.djangoproject.com)'
STATICFILES_FINDERS 
('django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder')
SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN   
None
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME 
'sessionid'
ADMIN_FOR   
()
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
('%H:%M:%S', '%H:%M')
DATABASES   
{'default': {'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
         'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
         'NAME': 'osqa',
         'OPTIONS': {},
         'PASSWORD': '********************',
         'PORT': '',
         'TEST_CHARSET': None,
         'TEST_COLLATION': None,
         'TEST_MIRROR': None,
         'TEST_NAME': None,
         'TIME_ZONE': 'Australia/Melbourne',
         'USER': 'uosqa'}}
TEST_DATABASE_NAME  
None
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS 
None
FILE_UPLOAD_HANDLERS    
('django.core.files.uploadhandler.MemoryFileUploadHandler',
 'django.core.files.uploadhandler.TemporaryFileUploadHandler')
DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE    
'text/html'
OSQA_DEFAULT_SKIN   
'default'
APPEND_SLASH    
True
FIRST_DAY_OF_WEEK   
0
DATABASE_ROUTERS    
[]
YEAR_MONTH_FORMAT   
'F Y'
STATICFILES_STORAGE 
'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage'
CACHES  
{'default': {'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
         'LOCATION': '/usr/local/src/osqa/cache'}}
MODULES_FOLDER  
'/usr/local/src/osqa/forum_modules'
SERVER_EMAIL    
USE_I18N    
True
THOUSAND_SEPARATOR  
','
SECRET_KEY  
'********************'
LANGUAGE_COOKIE_NAME    
'django_language'
FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR    
'/usr/local/src/osqa/tmp'
TRANSACTIONS_MANAGED    
False
LOGGING_CONFIG  
'django.utils.log.dictConfig'
TEMPLATE_LOADERS    
['django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source',
 'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source',
 'forum.modules.template_loader.module_templates_loader',
 'forum.skins.load_template_source']
TEMPLATE_DEBUG  
True
CSRF_COOKIE_NAME    
'csrftoken'
TEST_DATABASE_COLLATION 
None
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD 
'********************'
CACHE_BACKEND   
'file:///usr/local/src/osqa/cache'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE   
False
CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN  
None
FILE_CHARSET    
'utf-8'
DEBUG   
True
MODULES_PACKAGE 
'forum_modules'
SESSION_FILE_PATH   
None
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE    
'django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage'
INSTALLED_APPS  
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'django.contrib.markup',
 'forum']
LANGUAGES   
(('ar', 'Arabic'),
 ('az', 'Azerbaijani'),
 ('zh-cn', 'Simplified Chinese'),
 ('zh-tw', 'Traditional Chinese'))
DATABASE_ENGINE 
'postgresql_psycopg2'
DATABASE_NAME   
'osqa'
COMMENTS_FIRST_FEW  
0
PREPEND_WWW 
False
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY 
False
DATABASE_PORT   
''
DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS  
False
MONTH_DAY_FORMAT    
'F j'
LOGIN_URL   
'/accounts/login/'
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE 
False
TIME_FORMAT 
'P'
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS  
('%Y-%m-%d',
 '%d %B, %Y')
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS 
['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME   
''
PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS 
'********************'
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS  
'default'
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST  
False
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX  
'/admin_media/'
NUMBER_GROUPING 
0
SESSION_ENGINE  
'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW   
'django.views.csrf.csrf_failure'
COMMENTS_SKETCHY_USERS_GROUP    
None
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL  
'/accounts/profile/'
SESSION_COOKIE_PATH 
'/'
LOGGING 
{'disable_existing_loggers': False,
 'handlers': {'mail_admins': {'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
                  'level': 'ERROR'}},
 'loggers': {'django.request': {'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
                'level': 'ERROR',
                'propagate': True}},
 'version': 1}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_KEY_PREFIX 
''
LOCALE_PATHS    
()
TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID  
''
COMMENTS_ALLOW_PROFANITIES  
False
LOGOUT_URL  
'/accounts/logout/'
EMAIL_USE_TLS   
False
TEMPLATE_DIRS   
('/usr/local/src/osqa/forum/skins',)
FIXTURE_DIRS    
()
EMAIL_HOST  
'localhost'
DATE_FORMAT 
'N j, Y'
MEDIA_ROOT  
''
ADMINS  
()
FORMAT_MODULE_PATH  
None
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL  
'webmaster@localhost'
STATICFILES_DIRS    
()
MEDIA_URL   
''
DATETIME_FORMAT 
'N j, Y, P'
EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX    
'[Django] '
DJANGO_VERSION  
1.3
SITE_ID 
1
DISALLOWED_USER_AGENTS  
()
ALLOWED_INCLUDE_ROOTS   
()
DECIMAL_SEPARATOR   
'.'
SHORT_DATE_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y'
DATABASE_USER   
'uosqa'
MODULE_LIST 
[<module 'osqa.forum_modules.sximporter' from '/usr/local/src/osqa/forum_modules/sximporter/__init__.pyc'>,
 <module 'osqa.forum_modules.pgfulltext' from '/usr/local/src/osqa/forum_modules/pgfulltext/__init__.pyc'>,
 <module 'osqa.forum_modules.default_badges' from '/usr/local/src/osqa/forum_modules/default_badges/__init__.pyc'>,
 <module 'osqa.forum_modules.akismet' from '/usr/local/src/osqa/forum_modules/akismet/__init__.pyc'>,
 <module 'osqa.forum_modules.exporter' from '/usr/local/src/osqa/forum_modules/exporter/__init__.pyc'>,
 <module 'osqa.forum_modules.localauth' from '/usr/local/src/osqa/forum_modules/localauth/__init__.pyc'>,
 <module 'osqa.forum_modules.robotstxt' from '/usr/local/src/osqa/forum_modules/robotstxt/__init__.pyc'>,
 <module 'osqa.forum_modules.facebookauth' from '/usr/local/src/osqa/forum_modules/facebookauth/__init__.pyc'>,
 <module 'osqa.forum_modules.oauthauth' from '/usr/local/src/osqa/forum_modules/oauthauth/__init__.pyc'>]
TEST_RUNNER 
'django.test.simple.DjangoTestSuiteRunner'
SITE_SRC_ROOT   
'/usr/local/src/osqa'
TIME_ZONE   
'Australia/Melbourne'
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE 
2621440
APP_BASE_URL    
'http://127.0.0.1'
EMAIL_BACKEND   
'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_TABLESPACE  
''
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS 
['django.core.context_processors.request',
 'forum.context.application_settings',
 'forum.user_messages.context_processors.user_messages',
 'django.core.context_processors.auth']
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE  
1209600
ONLINE_USERS    
{}
SETTINGS_MODULE 
'osqa.settings'
USE_ETAGS   
False
DISABLED_MODULES    
['books', 'recaptcha', 'project_badges']
LANGUAGES_BIDI  
('he', 'ar', 'fa')
DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE    
''
INTERNAL_IPS    
('127.0.0.1',)
STATIC_URL  
None
EMAIL_PORT  
25
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT   
'm/d/Y P'
ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES  
{}
DATABASE_OPTIONS    
{}
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS    
600
BANNED_IPS  
()
DEBUG_TOOLBAR_CONFIG    
{'INTERCEPT_REDIRECTS': True}
DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS  
('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
 '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
 '%Y-%m-%d',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%Y',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S',
 '%m/%d/%y %H:%M',
 '%m/%d/%y')
DATABASE_PASSWORD   
'********************'
COMMENTS_MODERATORS_GROUP   
None
PROFANITIES_LIST    
'********************'
EMAIL_HOST_USER 
''
COMMENTS_BANNED_USERS_GROUP 
None
You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 500 page.
```

**Edit:
The urls.py file:**

```
import startup
import os.path
from forum import settings
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf import settings as djsettings
from django.contrib import admin
from forum import views as app
from forum.sitemap import OsqaSitemap
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
import logging

admin.autodiscover()

sitemaps = {
    'questions': OsqaSitemap
}

APP_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)

core_urls = (
    url(r'^$', app.readers.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^%s(.*)' % _('nimda/'), include(admin.site.urls)),                        url(r'^sitemap.xml$', 'forum.sitemap.index', {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
    url(r'^sitemap-(?P<section>.+)\.xml$', 'forum.sitemap.sitemap', {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),

    url(r'^favicon\.ico$', app.meta.favicon),
    url(r'^cstyle\.css$', app.meta.custom_css, name='custom_css'),

    url(r'^m/(?P<skin>\w+)/media/(?P<path>.*)$', app.meta.media , name='osqa_media'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<path>.*)$' % _('upfiles/'), 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': os.path.join(APP_PATH, 'upfiles').replace('\\', '/')}, name='uploaded_file',),

    url(r'^%s$' % _('faq/'), app.meta.static, {'content': settings.FAQ_PAGE_TEXT, 'title': _('FAQ')}, name='faq'),
    url(r'^%s$' % _('about/'), app.meta.static, {'content': settings.ABOUT_PAGE_TEXT, 'title': _('About')}, name='about'),
    url(r'^%s$' % _('markdown_help/'), app.meta.markdown_help, name='markdown_help'), url(r'^opensearch\.xml$', app.meta.opensearch, name='opensearch'),
    url(r'^opensearch\.xml$', app.meta.opensearch, name='opensearch'),
    url(r'^%s$' % _('privacy/'), app.meta.privacy, name='privacy'),
    url(r'^%s$' % _('logout/'), app.meta.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/%s$' % (_('answers/'), _('edit/')), app.writers.edit_answer, name='edit_answer'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/$' % _('revisions/'), app.readers.revisions, name='revisions'),
    url(r'^%s$' % _('questions/'), app.readers.questions, name='questions'),
    url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('questions/'), _('ask/')), app.writers.ask, name='ask'),
    url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('questions/'), _('related_questions/')), app.commands.related_questions, name='related_questions'),

    url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('questions/'), _('unanswered/')), app.readers.unanswered, name='unanswered'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<mode>[\w\-]+)/(?P<user>\d+)/(?P<slug>.*)/$' % _('questions/'), app.readers.user_questions, name='user_questions'),


    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/%s$' % (_('questions/'), _('edit/')), app.writers.edit_question, name='edit_question'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/%s$' % (_('questions/'), _('close/')), app.commands.close, kwargs=dict(close=True), name='close'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/%s$' % (_('questions/'), _('reopen/')), app.commands.close, kwargs=dict(close=False), name='reopen'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/%s$' % (_('questions/'), _('answer/')), app.writers.answer, name='answer'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<action>\w+)/$' % _('pending-data/'), app.writers.manage_pending_data, name='manage_pending_data'),

    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<vote_type>[a-z]+)/' % _('vote/'), app.commands.vote_post, name='vote_post'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/$' % _('like_comment/'), app.commands.like_comment, name='like_comment'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/' % _('comment/'), app.commands.comment, name='comment'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/$' % _('delete_comment/'), app.commands.delete_comment, name='delete_comment'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/$' % _('convert_comment/'), app.commands.convert_comment_to_answer, name='convert_comment'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/$' % _('accept_answer/'), app.commands.accept_answer, name='accept_answer'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/$' % _('answer_link/'), app.commands.answer_permanent_link, name='answer_permanent_link'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/$' % _('mark_favorite/'), app.commands.mark_favorite, name='mark_favorite'),
    url(r'^%s%s(?P<user_id>\d+)/%s(?P<answer_id>\d+)/$' % (_('award_points/'), _('user/'), _('answer/')), app.commands.award_points, name='award_points'),

    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/' % _('flag/'), app.commands.flag_post, name='flag_post'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/' % _('delete/'), app.commands.delete_post, name='delete_post'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<user>\d+)?$' % _('subscribe/'), app.commands.subscribe, name='subscribe'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/$' % _('subscribe/'), app.commands.subscribe, name='subscribe_simple'),
    url(r'^%s' % _('matching_tags/'), app.commands.matching_tags, name='matching_tags'),
    url(r'^%s' % _('matching_users/'), app.commands.matching_users, name='matching_users'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/' % _('node_markdown/'), app.commands.node_markdown, name='node_markdown'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/' % _('convert/'), app.commands.convert_to_comment, name='convert_to_comment'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/' % _('convert_to_question/'), app.writers.convert_to_question,name='convert_to_question'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/' % _('wikify/'), app.commands.wikify, name='wikify'),

    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]*)$' % _('question/'), 'django.views.generic.simple.redirect_to', {'url': '/questions/%(id)s/%(slug)s'}),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/?$' % _('questions/'), app.readers.question, name='question'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>.*)/(?P<answer>\d+)$' % _('questions/'), app.readers.question),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>.*)$' % _('questions/'), app.readers.question, name='question'),


    url(r'^%s$' % _('tags/'), app.readers.tags, name='tags'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<tag>.*)/$' % _('tags/'), app.readers.tag, name='tag_questions'),     
    url(r'^%s%s(?P<tag>[^/]+)/$' % (_('mark-tag/'),_('interesting/')), app.commands.mark_tag, kwargs={'reason':'good','action':'add'}, name='mark_interesting_tag'),     
    url(r'^%s%s(?P<tag>[^/]+)/$' % (_('mark-tag/'),_('ignored/')), app.commands.mark_tag, kwargs={'reason':'bad','action':'add'}, name='mark_ignored_tag'),     
    url(r'^%s(?P<tag>[^/]+)/$' % _('unmark-tag/'), app.commands.mark_tag, kwargs={'action':'remove'}, name='mark_ignored_tag'),     

    url(r'^%s$' % _('users/'), app.users.users, name='users'),
    # url(r'^%s$' % _('online_users/'), app.users.online_users, name='online_users'),    

    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/%s$' % (_('users/'), _('edit/')), app.users.edit_user, name='edit_user'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/%s$' % (_('users/'), _('award/')), app.users.award_points, name='user_award_points'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/%s$' % (_('users/'), _('suspend/')), app.users.suspend, name='user_suspend'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/%s(?P<action>[a-z]+)/(?P<status>[a-z]+)/$' % (_('users/'), _('powers/')), app.users.user_powers, name='user_powers'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>.*)/%s$' % (_('users/'), _('subscriptions/')), app.users.user_subscriptions, name='user_subscriptions'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>.*)/%s$' % (_('users/'), _('preferences/')), app.users.user_preferences, name='user_preferences'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>.*)/%s$' % (_('users/'), _('favorites/')), app.users.user_favorites, name='user_favorites'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>.*)/%s$' % (_('users/'), _('reputation/')), app.users.user_reputation, name='user_reputation'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>.*)/%s$' % (_('users/'), _('votes/')), app.users.user_votes, name='user_votes'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>.*)/%s$' % (_('users/'), _('recent/')), app.users.user_recent, name='user_recent'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>.*)/$' % _('users/'), app.users.user_profile, name='user_profile'),
    url(r'^%s$' % _('badges/'), app.meta.badges, name='badges'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/?$' % _('badges/'), app.meta.badge, name='badge'),
    # (r'^admin/doc/' % _('admin/doc'), include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

    url(r'^%s$' % _('upload/'), app.writers.upload, name='upload'),
    url(r'^%s$' % _('search/'), app.readers.search, name='search'),
    url(r'^%s$' % _('contact/'), app.meta.feedback, name='feedback'),

    (r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),

    url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('account/'), _('signin/')), app.auth.signin_page, name='auth_signin'),
    url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('account/'), _('signout/')), app.auth.signout, name='user_signout'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<provider>\w+)/%s$' % (_('account/'), _('signin/')), app.auth.prepare_provider_signin, name='auth_provider_signin'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<provider>\w+)/%s$' % (_('account/'), _('done/')), app.auth.process_provider_signin, name='auth_provider_done'),
    url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('account/'), _('register/')), app.auth.external_register, name='auth_external_register'),
    url(r'^%s%s(?P<user>\d+)/(?P<code>.+)/$' % (_('account/'), _('validate/')), app.auth.validate_email, name='auth_validate_email'),
    url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('account/'), _('tempsignin/')), app.auth.request_temp_login, name='auth_request_tempsignin'),
    url(r'^%s%s(?P<user>\d+)/(?P<code>.+)/$' % (_('account/'), _('tempsignin/')), app.auth.temp_signin, name='auth_tempsignin'),
    url(r'^%s(?P<id>\d+)/%s$' % (_('account/'), _('authsettings/')), app.auth.auth_settings, name='user_authsettings'),
    url(r'^%s%s(?P<id>\d+)/%s$' % (_('account/'), _('providers/'), _('remove/')), app.auth.remove_external_provider, name='user_remove_external_provider'),
    url(r'^%s%s%s$' % (_('account/'), _('providers/'), _('add/')), app.auth.signin_page, name='user_add_external_provider'),
    url(r'^%s%s$' %(_('account/'), _('send-validation/')), app.auth.send_validation_email, name='send_validation_email'),


    url(r'^%s$' % _('admin/'), app.admin.dashboard, name='admin_index'),
    url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('admin/'), _('switch_interface/')), app.admin.interface_switch, name='admin_switch_interface'),
    url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('admin/'), _('statistics/')), app.admin.statistics, name='admin_statistics'),
    url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('admin/'), _('denormalize/')), app.admin.recalculate_denormalized, name='admin_denormalize'),
    url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('admin/'), _('go_bootstrap/')), app.admin.go_bootstrap, name='admin_go_bootstrap'),
    url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('admin/'), _('go_defaults/')), app.admin.go_defaults, name='admin_go_defaults'),
    url(r'^%s%s(?P<set_name>\w+)/(?P<var_name>\w+)/$' % (_('admin/'), _('settings/')), app.admin.get_default, name='admin_default'),
    url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('admin/'), _('maintenance/')), app.admin.maintenance, name='admin_maintenance'),
    url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('admin/'), _('flagged_posts/')), app.admin.flagged_posts, name='admin_flagged_posts'),
    url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('admin/'), _('static_pages/')), app.admin.static_pages, name='admin_static_pages'),

    url(r'^%s%s%s$' % (_('admin/'), _('static_pages/'), _('new/')), app.admin.edit_page, name='admin_new_page'),
    url(r'^%s%s%s(?P<id>\d+)/$' % (_('admin/'), _('static_pages/'), _('edit/')), app.admin.edit_page, name='admin_edit_page'),

    url(r'^%s%s(?P<name>\w+)/$' % (_('admin/'), _('tools/')), app.admin.tools_page, name='admin_tools'),

    url(r'^%s%s(?P<set_name>\w+)/$' % (_('admin/'), _('settings/')), app.admin.settings_set, name='admin_set'),

    url(r'%s%s' % (_('admin/'), _('test_email_settings/')), app.admin.test_email_settings, name='test_email_settings'),

    url(r'^feeds/rss[/]?$', app.readers.feed, name='latest_questions_feed'),

)

from forum.modules import get_modules_script

module_patterns = get_modules_script('urls')

urlpatterns = patterns('')

for pattern_file in module_patterns:
    pattern = getattr(pattern_file, 'urlpatterns', None)
    if pattern:
    urlpatterns += pattern

module_defined = {}

for t in urlpatterns:
    if hasattr(t, 'name') and t.name:
    module_defined[t.name] = True

core_defined = []

for u in core_urls:
    if not(hasattr(u, 'name') and u.name and (u.name in module_defined)):
    core_defined.append(u)

def urlname(name):
    if name in module_defined:
    return None
    return name

urlpatterns += patterns('', *core_defined)
```

Comment: Needs more information. Probably can't debug that without having your urls.py.

Comment: Show us relative parts of `urls.py`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Reverse for 'ask_to_me' with arguments '(2, u'allenq')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

**The Django template renderer is not able to find the reverse URL.**

This means you used a {% url ... %} tag somewhere, with arguments that couldn't match an URL in your urls.py.

Make sure the `ask_to_me` URL pattern exists in urls.py. You can try to use reverse() in the Django command line for that.

Then, make sure that it takes two **unnamed** arguments, one integer (here, 2) and one string (here, 'allenq').

I cannot provide you an out-of-the-box solution, as you didn't give us enough information. We need the urls.py and the code of template, at least the part where you use the {% url ... %} tag. Also, you only asked information for "pointing out where the problem would be", so... there you go.

### Edit after more info :

So the template tag with the error is :

```
{% url ask_to_me view_user.id view_user.username%}
```

This error is caused by the fact that there is **no pattern** with the name "ask_to_me". Only this one contains the word "ask" :

```
url(r'^%s%s$' % (_('questions/'), _('ask/')), app.writers.ask, name='ask'),
```

However, it does not take arguments. You need to find where is that view gone. Try to look inside the lower parts of your urls.py, where URL patterns are added dynamically from "modules".

Comment: Thanks Pistache, I've attached the urls.py file. I will also investigate according to your hint.